# IBDesignable view causes endless rebuilding

Tags: ios, xcode, interface-builder

I'm writing a UIView subclass that uses both IBInspectable and IBDesignable. I'm not doing anything unusual, but my subclass causes Xcode 6.2 to endlessly rebuild the project. My Identity Inspector shows this state oscillation under the heading 'Designables':

[image: 'Designables' state oscillating between 'Updating' and 'Up to date']

Every time the build restarts, the inspector loses focus. This makes it hard to edit anything from IB, which defeats the purpose of writing this class in the first place.

Here is the implementation of my DesignableTestView:

```
import UIKit
@IBDesignable class DesignableTestView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var testBackground:UIColor? {
        didSet {
            if testBackground != nil {
                self.backgroundColor = testBackground
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to change my code or settings of Xcode to prevent the constant rebuilding?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm wonder if this designable view class is part of the current target. In WWDC 2014 video [What's New in Interface Builder](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/?id=411), in the Live Views demonstration, they describe that the first step is to ensure that the designable class is in a separate custom framework target. That video demonstrates the process for creating this custom framework target within the project.

If that's not issue. I'd suggest cleaning your project ("Clean" on "Product" menu) and rebuilding just the custom framework target to make sure that's ok before you try doing anything in IB, itself. Bottom line, make sure that the framework can be built without incident. If the problem still persists after doing that, I'd take it to the next level and (a) find the Xcode derived data folder; (b) quit Xcode; (c) clear the derived data folder, (d) restart Xcode, and (e) trying building the framework target again.

**Edit:**
Above link seems to be dead. Video can be downloaded directly from: http://devstreaming.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2014/411xx0xo98zzoor/411/411_hd_whats_new_in_interface_builder.mov?dl=1

There is also a github gist with links to all the 2014 material: https://gist.github.com/jianpx/eea1e938d5868e980b11

Comment: They didn't explicitly say why, but in the introductory WWDC video, Apple was explicit regarding the need to do so. I suspect that it's for pragmatic purposes (it has to build the target to run in IB, and the state of your main target may not be buildable and/or may be too expensive for mere IB usage). Experimentally, I've tested it and it seems to work regardless of what target it's in, but Apple advises a separate target.

Comment: That might be required, because of build time and issues right. Now I stuck with endlessly rebuilding storyboard. I suspect multiple targets to be the problem. More detailed IB Builder output would be great.

Comment: The endless rebuilding is common when using a single target. I'd encourage you to keep the IBDesignables in a separate target from your main target (I've found it more reliable and Apple was explicit in advising that we do so). And if you have endless rebuilding even with the designables in separate target, I'd temporarily change to the designables target and try building just that and make sure you don't have some error there. If you still have problems, I'd suggest finding derived data folder, quit Xcode, empty the derived data folder, and then restart Xcode.

Comment: Is there someplace other than a video that this is documented?

Comment: I haven't seen much official documentation on designables at all. But Apple couldn't have been more specific on this point: They reiterate several times in that video that designables must be in separate target. With Xcode 8's evolving "incremental build" capabilities, maybe this requirement will be removed at some point, but not that I know of so far.

Comment: This answer is as helpful as this limitation is annoying! Thank you.

Comment: Xcode still rebuilds the whole app when I view a XIB file for some reason, even after I did this.

Comment: Don't forget to make your classes **public** once you move them into your framework. Spent too long with that part myself

Comment: Good point, anders. You either want to declare it `open` or `public` if you plan on programmatically interacting with this from a different module/target.

Answer (score 9):

I was still having this issue (in Xcode 8.3.3) even after moving my IBDesignable classes into a separate framework. What worked for me was to open the offending Xib file, uncheck *Editor > Automatically Refresh Views*, and then restart Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I was ALSO still having this issue Xcode 9.3 even after moving all IBDesignables and IBInspectables to a separate framework (and clean all, kill derived data). IB would continue to rebuild the main target and its dependencies.

The solution I found here https://www.e-learn.cn/content/wangluowenzhang/307740 solved it:

1. remove all `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`
2. clean all, clear derived data, close Xcode
3. reopen Xcode, force IB to rebuild with no IBDesignables (Editor -> RefreshAllViews should be greyed out not)
4. close Xcode
5. add all `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable` back
6. reopen Xcode
7. RefreshAllViews should be available, click it.
8. voila, IB never only rebuilds framework from now on

Clearly there was something funky cached in Xcode that cleanall/killing derived data didn't wipe.