# Xcode - Is there a way to disable all IBInspectable temporarily, to speed up Storyboard?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard, ibdesignable, ibinspectable

I really like `IBInspectable` and `IBDesignable` features, that allow to speed up things and have a better view of final result, directly in Storyboard. But Gosh…they slow down soooo much my storyboard loading, and makes it very laggy every time I edit a controller that include a view with `IBInspectable`. It is barely unusable (on 2018 MBP, 16GO RAM). The two libs I have that use `IBInspectable` are [PMSuperButton](https://github.com/pmusolino/PMSuperButton) and [Hero](https://github.com/HeroTransitions/Hero).

Note that it is NOT rebuilding, contrarily to this question : [IBDesignable view causes endless rebuilding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260077/ibdesignable-view-causes-endless-rebuilding). Also note that unticking `Automatically Refresh Views` doesn't change anything.

So I'm searching for a way to temporarily disable all of them, as most often I don't need them.

I was thinking of a macro that would be able to toggle it :

```
#define IBInspectable_togglable IBInspectable //enabled
//#define IBInspectable_togglable //disabled
```

But this doesn't do the job. And even if it has worked, I had no clue for Swift, which doesn't support macros.

Does anyone has any idea to perform this ?

Comment: M finding the same thing, had any luck yet?

Comment: @NikhilManapure Unfortunately I haven’t found a solution yet... Still searching though!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to close the project, and open up the `xib` or `storyboard` in Xcode without opening the whole project.

That will stop customized `IBInspectable` from loading.

This will allow you to get a great experience in designing the whole view without lags in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the whole extension that has these @IBInspectable variables, finish your other changes on the storyboard, and uncomment it again when you want to run the project.